# UWP XAML Design Error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 0x80073D0F

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

Error loading UI XAML design.

[image]

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Falha na operação de
>   implantação porque o aplicativo especificado precisa ser registrado
>   primeiro. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D0F)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String
>   appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options,
>   Int32& processId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.DesignerWrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String
>   appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site, Boolean
>   isRunningElevated)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String
>   appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String
>   applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary
>   environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory
>   factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo,
>   IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry&
>   entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo
>   culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

---

[image]

Comment: Did you use the x64 dll in xaml?

Comment: I think you may reinstall the VisualStudio (〒︿〒)

Comment: I try to call Microsoft to send this. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback